# Missing argument and undefined variable error in the below code?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, php-5.4

```
2015-08-13T10:44:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for EkoInternetMarketing_AllReviews_Block_AllReviews::getReviews(), called in /chroot/home/website/website.com/html/app/code/community/EkoInternetMarketing/AllReviews/Block/AllReviews.php on line 113 and defined  in /chroot/home/website/website.com/html/app/code/community/EkoInternetMarketing/AllReviews/Block/AllReviews.php on line 5
2015-08-13T10:44:13+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: numberOfReviews  in /chroot/home/website/website.com/html/app/code/community/EkoInternetMarketing/AllReviews/Block/AllReviews.php on line 12
```

file code is as below:

```
<?php
class EkoInternetMarketing_AllReviews_Block_AllReviews extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function getReviews($numberOfReviews){

        $_reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
            ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
            ->setDateOrder('desc')
            ->setPageSize($numberOfReviews)
            ->addRateVotes();

        return $_reviews;
    }

    public function getProductDetails(){



    }

    public function getAllReviews(){

        // Get the number of reviews to display
        $numberOfReviews = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/number_of_reviews');

        // Get the reviews
        $_reviews = $this->getReviews($numberOfReviews);

        // Get the settings
        $enable_product_image = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_product_image');
        $enable_totals = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_totals');

        $data['settings']['number_of_columns'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/number_of_columns');
        $data['settings']['enable_review_nickname'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_review_nickname');
        $data['settings']['enable_review_title'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_review_title');
        $data['settings']['enable_review_date'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_review_date');
        $data['settings']['enable_review_stars'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_review_stars');
        $data['settings']['enable_totals'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_totals');
        $data['settings']['enable_rich_snippet'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_rich_snippet');
        $data['settings']['enable_module_credit'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/enable_module_credit');

        if($enable_totals == "1"):
            $data['totals'] = $this->getTotalReviews();
        endif;

        $i=0;
        foreach($_reviews as $review):

            $data['reviews'][$i]['review_title'] = $review->getTitle();
            $data['reviews'][$i]['review_nickname'] = $review->getNickname();
            $data['reviews'][$i]['review_created_at'] = $this->formatCreatedDate($review->getCreatedAt(), "m/d/Y");
            $data['reviews'][$i]['review_detail'] = $review->getDetail();
            $data['reviews'][$i]['review_percentage'] = $this->getReviewFinalPercentage($review->getRatingVotes());

            if($enable_product_image == "1"):

                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($review->getData('entity_pk_value'));

                $data['reviews'][$i]['product_image'] = '<a href="'.$_product->getProductUrl().'" title="'.$this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true).'" class="product-image"><img src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(80).'" width="80" height="80" alt="'.$this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true).'" /></a>';

            endif;


            $i++;
        endforeach;

        return $data;
    }

    public function formatCreatedDate($date, $format){

        $date = strtotime($date);
        $reviewDate = date($format, $date);

        return $reviewDate;
    }

    public function getReviewFinalPercentage($votes){

        $cumulativeRating = 0;
        $j=0;
        foreach( $votes as $vote ) {
            $cumulativeRating +=$vote->getPercent();
            $j++;
        }

        $finalPercentage = 0;
        if ($cumulativeRating != 0){
            $finalPercentage = ($cumulativeRating/$j);
        }

        return $finalPercentage;
    }

    public function getModuleCredit(){

        $showModuleCreditValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/show_module_credit');

        $credit = 'Magento Module By <a href="http://www.ekoim.com">EKO Internet Marketing</a>';

        if($showModuleCreditValue == "0"):
            $credit = '<a href="http://www.ekoim.com" style="display: none;">EKO Internet Marketing</a>';
        endif;

        return $credit;     
    }

    public function getTotalReviews(){

        $_reviews = $this->getReviews();

        $i=0;
        $cumulativePercentage = 0;
        foreach($_reviews as $review):

            $cumulativePercentage = $cumulativePercentage + $this->getReviewFinalPercentage($review->getRatingVotes());

            $i++;   
        endforeach;

        $totalReviewRating['total_reviews'] = $i;
        $totalReviewRating['total_percentage'] = ceil($cumulativePercentage / $i);
        $totalReviewRating['total_of_five'] = round($totalReviewRating['total_percentage'] / 100 * 5, 2);

        return $totalReviewRating;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `Mage::getStoreConfig('ekoim/allreviews/number_of_reviews');` returns a value?

Comment: I am not sure. Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually isn't a Magento-related problem but a simple PHP mistake. You're calling the function

```
$_reviews = $this->getReviews();
```

on line 113 as stated in the exception stack. The funciton `getReviews` requires an argument `$numberOfReviews`, though:

```
public function getReviews($numberOfReviews)
```

Change the line 113 to

```
$_reviews = $this->getReviews(0);
```

or change the method signature to

```
public function getReviews($numberOfReviews = 0)
```